# css breadcrumbs using an image sprite

Tags: css

I have an image and i need to use that as the breadcrumb background image. I tried but doesnt seem to be coming correctly. I have created a fiddle for this. Can somebody please help me what I am doing wrong. I am not supposed to change the html since teh same file is being used in other applications also. Only the css, I can change.

HTML

```
<div id="itemDisplay">
   <a href="www.abc.com" class="step1only"><span id="step1" class="step_on" title="Home">Home</span></a>
   <span id="step2" class="step_off" title="Vehicle">Vehicle</span>
   <span id="step3" class="step_off" title="Vans &amp; Trucks">Vans &amp; Trucks</span>
   <span id="step4" class="step_off" title="Vanagon">Vanagon</span>
</div>
```

I have attached an image how the actual breadcrumb should look like
[image]

In my fiddle the alignment of the text is not correct except for the first text. The text should be aligned towards left. Also the last breadcrumb is not correct.
When the user is in the first page, only the first breadcrumb text should be bold, when he navigates to second page, only the second should be bold

http://jsfiddle.net/Dbudt/5/

Please advice

Comment: *nly the first breadcrumb text should be bold, when he navigates to second page, only the second should be bold* You cannot do this with CSS only, as far as the alignment goes, you've extra amount of `width` http://jsfiddle.net/Dbudt/6/

Comment: @Mr.Alien: thanks fr the reply..the last box should not have triangle ending..any help?

Comment: You will have to change the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Updated demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Dbudt/9/)

I've added `.active` class so you can use it on span on the page you need.
I've also fixed the padding for `span.step_off`

[**UPDATE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Dbudt/13/)

I fix the `background-position` for the last element.

Comment: @Mihey..Thanks for the reply..The problem is I should not make any changes in the html since the same file is being used in other applications as well. So only by using css is it possibel? And also the last box should not have the triangle end...Any help?